# Styled HTML element looks different when printed

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a pretty simple HTML document, a visual representation of a card, that is sent to people who purchase a gift card via our website. The dollar amount is added to the background image and is styled by CSS. Like I said. Pretty simple.

On screen, the dollar amount (in the upper right) shows as white, which is what I want.

[How it appears on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRIoe.jpg)

But when printed (and in print preview), the dollar amount is a dark gray, which makes it hard to see against the background.

[How it appears when printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CchyI.jpg)

The same thing happens regardless of which browser the customer uses. I've tested it myself on Chrome and Safari with the same results. Depending on the customer's printer, the dollar amount can be very difficult to read.

Any color other than white seems to work fine. When I look at printer emulation in Inspect Element, red CSS appears red, and it will print as red; black CSS appears black, and it will print as black; but while white CSS appears white, it will print as *gray* every time. This is driving me crazy, and I'm sure it's a simple solution.

We need for customers to be able to print these e-gift cards legibly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Story of my life: I work on a problem for hours, post a question asking for help, and almost immediately figure out the answer.

The issue appears to be that browsers don't want to print white when it appears on a web page. Makes sense. White wouldn't show up on white paper, so it makes it gray.

The solution seems to be to add `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` to the styles. At least that works for Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Thank you!! It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

With my worked, in print they have some different css style code to display.
You can use

```
@media print { //your css code }
```

and check results.
I suggest to use table layout in all page.